# Unable to change keyboard brightness on Ubuntu 14.04 login screen

Tags: brightness, keyboard-backlight

I own an Asus N551JK laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. It works very well but at login screen,  it seems that the system cannot "remember"  past keyboard and screen brightness configuration, setting both to maximum. I've created a script (in /etc/rc.local) which set screen brightness at a certain level at boot,  but no luck for the keyboard brightness: it can be only changed with another script  only after login.  Is there a way to workaround this bug?